# Running cargo test errors with "please recompile that crate using this compiler"

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My `Cargo.toml` file looks like this:

```
[dependencies]
unicode-segmentation = "1.10.0"

[package]
edition = "2021"
name = "reverse_string"
version = "1.2.0"
```

There is a dependency of [unicode-segmentation](https://github.com/unicode-rs/unicode-segmentation).

I am using rustc 1.64 and when I run `cargo test`, I get this error:

> help: please recompile that crate using this compiler (rustc 1.62.1) (consider running `cargo clean` first)
> = note: the following crate versions were found:
> crate `unicode_segmentation` compiled by rustc 1.64.0

Comment: It looks like what?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze oops, I have added the code from the file

Comment: I created an empty project with the same `Cargo.toml` and didn't have any issues. Either this isn't the whole problem and your code does something weird, or this was a one time compiler fluke. Did running `cargo clean` helped?

Comment: Also you didn't show error message (and the code that caused it), but only the "help" part of it. Show these as well to help us better understand the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had this problem on a mac and I had installed rust with both brew and rustup.  I uninstalled the brew version.

`brew uninstall rust`

Comment: there is only 1 rust.   When I run `where rustc` or `where cargo` they both point to 1 location and I never installed rust with cargo